# Django loaddata command from docker container

Tags: django, docker

I have a django app that I put inside of a docker container for deployment. I have some initial data that I want to load into the database via the `dumpdata` and `loaddata` commands. The initial data lives on my local hard drive. I choose a very naive approach and simply copied the `data_backup.json` file to the server via `scp`.

Now, I want to load the data_backup.json file (the file sits on the server not in the docker container) by executing:

```
sudo docker-compose exec restapi python manage.py loaddata --settings=rest.settings.production ./data_backup_20191004.json
```

But Django only searches the internal directories for fixtures.

**I am looking for a way to populate the database with the data_backup.json file inside the docker container. Can someone help?**

Ultimately, I am looking for a way to dump data directly to S3 and load it from there if needed (for db backups). If you have any tips on how to achieve that, this would also be super helpful - I don't seem to be able to find material on that.

Answer (score 11):

Just in case someone has this question in the future. It is possible to loaddata from stdin. So you can just take the backup file and pipe it into the database (within the container with a command like this:

```
cat <<fixture_name.json>> | sudo docker exec -i <<container_name_or_id>> python manage.py loaddata --format=json -
```

The last dash tells django that you want to load the data from stdin.

[DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#loaddata)

Comment: interesting, thank you. I don't have my container at hand but would like to give it a try and get back to you!

Comment: It took me a minute to realize those angle brackets are not bash redirects. Good answer btw.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the file into the docker container before running the command with `docker cp`:

```
docker cp ./data_backup_20191004.json <container_id>:django_dir/data_backup_20191004.json
```

Or, if the file is located on an S3 server, you could execute a curl inside the docker container and install from there:

```
sudo docker-compose exec restapi curl http://s3.example.com/path/to/data.json > data.json
sudo docker-compose exec restapi python manage.py loaddata --settings=rest.settings.production ./data.json
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for a way to populate the database with the
> data_backup.json file inside the docker container. Can someone help?

See the answer of Xen_mar, which I think it's perfect.

> Ultimately, I am looking for a way to dump data directly to S3 and
> load it from there if needed (for db backups). If you have any tips on
> how to achieve that, this would also be super helpful - I don't seem
> to be able to find material on that.

This seems to be a complete different question. I would consider using some django package like [Django Smuggler](https://pypi.org/project/django-smuggler/), which allows you to load and dump fixtures from the admin, and I assume that it may be possible to configure django smuggler upload directory to be handled by django storages. I'm not sure that is possible, so if you try let me know.